# Chrome Driver Exception in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape data from websites using selenium. The application is running on flask + uwsgi + nginx on aws ec2 instance.

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
service = Service("/opt/chromedriver")

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
def scrape_data(URL):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        driver.get(URL)
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        html_content = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
    except WebDriverException:
        driver.quit()
        print("Failed URL -->", URL)
    return html_content
url_x = input("Enter url : ")
raw_text = scrape_data(url_x)
```

**I am getting an error while executing this when accessed through nginx uwsgi but no error if I execute the code in CLI** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ubuntu/ml_eval/./main.py", line 98, in scrape_data
uwsgi[45145]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ml_eval/prjenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
uwsgi[45145]:     driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
uwsgi[45145]:     super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
uwsgi[45145]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ml_eval/prjenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
uwsgi[45145]:     RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
uwsgi[45145]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ml_eval/prjenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
uwsgi[45145]:     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
uwsgi[45145]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ml_eval/prjenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
uwsgi[45145]:     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
uwsgi[45145]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ml_eval/prjenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
uwsgi[45145]:     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
uwsgi[45145]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ml_eval/prjenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
uwsgi[45145]:     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
uwsgi[45145]: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
uwsgi[45145]:   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
uwsgi[45145]:   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
uwsgi[45145]: Stacktrace:
uwsgi[45145]: #0 0x55765c077ee3 <unknown>
```

How can this be solved ?

**Operating system : ubuntu 20.04

Python 3.8.10

ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947})

Google Chrome 96.0.4664.93

Google chrome location : /usr/bin/google-chrome**

Answer (score 2):

Add `:/usr/bin:/bin` to your PATH as shown below:

```
Environment="PATH=/home/artem/env/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

complete file looks like

```
$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/ml_eval.service

[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve flask app 
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/mleval
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/mleval/prjenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/mleval/prjenv/bin/uwsgi --ini mleval.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This helped me after digging many topics on this error. Thanks!